# how to define functions in ipython configuration file?

Tags: python, ipython

Using ipython 0.11 if I type a function definition, like

```
def f(s): print s
```

then I can use that function in that ipython session, but I don't know how to define that 
in the ipython_config.py file. 
If I just type the function definition in the file and try to use the function it it undefined.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two answers here:

First, for *super* simple functions like the one above, you can define them in `exec_lines`, e.g.:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [ "def f(s): print s" ]
```

(you can define arbitrarily complex functions this way, but it gets annoying beyond a couple of lines)

For more complicated code, you can write a script that you would like to run at startup, and add that to the `exec_files` list:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_files = [ "/path/to/myscript.py" ] 
# if you put the script in the profile dir, just the filename will suffice
```

We realized this is slightly annoying, so in 0.12, there will be a startup folder in profile directories, and anything you put in there will be run automatically.  This is essentially adding an extra `glob.glob('*.py')` to exec_files (which you can do yourself in 0.11, of course).

Comment: I put the script in the profile name but had to add the path of profile it did not work without it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to define a python file to run when ipython starts.  You can do this by setting the `exec_files` list:

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_files = [
        '/tmp/mymodule.py'
]
```

Then my file "/tmp/mymodule.py":

```
def foo():
    print "bar"
```

And finally, using this:

```
$ ipython

In [1]: foo()
bar
```

More information about the ipython config-file can be found here: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/ipython.html

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line functions can be defined in `*.py` and `*.ipy` files under the `startup` directory within the profile directory.

(Note that `*.ipy` and `*.py` files are treated differently.)

The profile directory can be discovered from the command line using

```
$ ipython locate profile
```