# How to set configuration file for ipython

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython

I would like ipython to add

```
from __future__ import division
```

by default when I run it.

I tried

```
ipython profile create
```

and then

```
emacs /home/foo/.config/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
```

However I can't tell what I should change in this file.  I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to the file:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['from __future__ import division']
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Armed with that answer I now see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032224/how-to-define-functions-in-ipython-configuration-file

Comment: Couldn't this clobber other exec_lines from earlier in the file?

Comment: @endolith, Yes, this could. If there's already `exec_lines`, prepend `from __future__ import division` .

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try

```
ipython -c 'from __future__ import division' -i
```

Comment: Would I have to do this every time? I want it to be the default so I can just run `ipython`.  I might for example also want to `import numpy as np` and I don't want to add them all to the command line.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to do it using the profiles but I don't know about it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what works for me. Open the file `$HOME/.ipython/ipy_user_conf.py`, add these lines:

```
import IPython.ipapi
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()
ip.options.autoexec.append('from __future__ import division')
```

Comment: I don't have those lines so I added them. I now get   File "/home/foo/.config/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py", line 470, in <module>
    o.autoexec.append('from __future__ import division')
NameError: name 'o' is not defined

Comment: @felix hm, I updated the answer, will it work like that?